# Why my program cutting out of the loop early?

Tags: assembly, mips

My program is supposed to take two integers, and an operator (division, multiplication, addition, subtraction). From there, it calculates the answer and remainder if necessary.

After, it is supposed to prompt the user if they want to make another calculation, with (y/n) options. If yes, it re-loops, and if not, the program exits. For some reason, it is not letting me put in an option for (y/n), and just skips my input and goes straight to termination. Here is my code. (Sorry beginner)

I also get an "Unknown Error Code 45" (pop up window?) right before I enter the operator.

[image]

```
# SPIM Calculator
# Computer Organization

    .data
prompt:         .asciiz "Welcome to SPIM Calculator 1.0!\n"
first_prompt:   .asciiz "Enter the first number: "
second_prompt:  .asciiz "Enter the second number: "
operator:       .asciiz "Enter the operation (+, -, *, /), then press enter key: "
error_message:  .asciiz "\n\nArgument is invalid. Try again!\n\n"
sp:             .asciiz " "
nl:             .asciiz "\n"
eq:             .asciiz " = "
parl:           .asciiz "("
parr:           .asciiz ")"
again_prompt:   .asciiz "\nWould you like to do another calculation? ( y / n ) "
ended_message:  .asciiz "\nCalculations complete."

    .globl main
    .text

main:
    #initialize
    li $s0, 10

    # Prompt welcome
    li $v0, 4           # print string value 4
    la $a0, prompt      # loads address from memory
    syscall

loop:

    # display prompt for q.1
    li $v0, 4           # loads value 4 into register v0 which is op code for print string
    la $a0, first_prompt    # loads address from memory, stores it in argument register
    syscall             # reads register $v0 for op code, sees 4 and prints string located in $a0

    # get input
    li $v0, 5           # load op code for getting an integer from user into register $v0
    syscall             # reads it and puts in $t0
    move $s0, $v0       # $s0 saves it


    # display prompt for q.2
    li $v0, 4           # loads value 4 into register v0 which is op code for print string
    la $a0, second_prompt   # loads address from memory, stores it in argument register
    syscall             # reads register $v0 for op code, sees 4 and prints string located in $a0

    # get input
    li $v0, 5           # load op code for getting an integer from user into register $v0
    syscall             # reads it and puts in $v0
    move $s1, $v0       # $s1 saves it


    # display prompt for q.3
    li $v0, 4           # loads value 4 into register v0 which is op code for print string
    la $a0, operator    # loads address from memory, stores it in argument register
    syscall             # reads register $v0 for op code, sees 4 and prints string located in $a0

    #get input
    li $v0, 12          # load op code for getting an symbol from user into register $v0
    syscall             # reads it and puts in $t0
    move $s2, $v0       # $s0 saves it


    # check symbol and use if statements to go to correct part in program
    beq $s2, '*', Multiplication
    beq $s2, '/', Division
    beq $s2, '-', Subtraction
    beq $s2, '+', Addition

    # in case it is none of these
    li $v0, 4               # print string value 4
    la $a0, error_message   # loads address from memory
    syscall


Multiplication:

    # perform multiplication
    mult $s0, $s1
    mflo $s3    # moves product to $s3
    syscall

    jr Print

Division:

    # perform division
    divu $s0, $s1
    mflo $s3    # moves quotient to $s3
    mfhi $s4    # move remainder to $s4
    syscall

    jr Print

Subtraction:

    # perform subtraction
    sub $s3, $s0, $s1   # moves result to $s3
    syscall

    jr Print

Addition:

    # perform addition
    add $s3, $s0, $s1   # moves result to $s3
    syscall

    jr Print

Print:
    # print new line
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, nl
    syscall

    # print first number
    li $v0, 1   # print int
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall

    # print space
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, sp
    syscall

    # print operator
    li $v0, 11      # print operator
    move $a0, $s2
    syscall

    # print space
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, sp
    syscall

    # print second number
    li $v0, 1       # print int
    move $a0, $s1
    syscall

    # print equals
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, eq
    syscall

    # jump to printing specifically for division
    beq $s2, '/', Division_Print

    # print result
    li $v0, 1       # print int
    move $a0, $s3
    syscall

    # print new line
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, nl
    syscall

    jr Again_Prompt

Division_Print:
    # print quotient
    li $v0, 1       # print int
    move $a0, $s3
    syscall

    # print space
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, sp
    syscall

    # print left parenthesis
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, parl
    syscall

    # print remainder
    li $v0, 1       # print int
    move $a0, $s4
    syscall

    # print right parenthesis
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, parr
    syscall

    # print new line
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, nl
    syscall

    jr Again_Prompt

Again_Prompt:
    # display prompt 
    li $v0, 4           # loads value 4 into register v0 which is op code for print string
    la $a0, again_prompt    # loads address from memory, stores it in argument register
    syscall             # reads register $v0 for op code, sees 4 and prints string located in $a0

    # get input
    li $v0, 12          # load op code for getting a character from user into register $v0
    syscall             # reads it and puts in $t0
    move $s6, $v0       # $s6 saves it

    # print new line
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, nl
    syscall

    # determine whether or not to do another calculation
    beq $s6, 'y', loop
    beq $s6, 'n', Terminate

Terminate:
    li $v0, 4           # loads value 4 into register v0 which is op code for print string
    la $a0, ended_message   # loads address from memory, stores it in argument register
    syscall             # reads register $v0 for op code, sees 4 and prints string located in $a0
    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is syscall 12, or rather the faulty assumptions that lead one to use it.

Consider momentarily the meaning of syscall 12 (read char), which will return from stdin 1 character. The problem is this:

The system prompts: `What operation would you like to perform?`, the user enters: `+\n`. Because stdin is line-buffered, the user has to press the enter key, meaning that at least two characters are put in the buffer when they only intended one. This means that when your program continues on to the next query: `Do you want to go again?`, there is still one character in the buffer: `\n` and this is what is returned by the second syscall 12.

Now that you understand the problem, I assume you can fix it. The best way is probably to convert the read character syscall to a read string syscall and examine the inputted string.

As a loose rule, do not use syscall 12 for user input from the keyboard.